# Find the smallest prime $p$ such that for any $1\leq k \leq 10$ relatively prime to $p$,one of $k,k^2,\ldots k^{p - 2}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find the smallest prime $p$ such that for any $1 \leq k \leq 10$ relatively prime to $p$, one of $k, k^2,\ldots k^{p - 2}$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

I am honestly not sure how to approach this problem, and would appreciate some help.

I think the logical approach is to use primitive roots and the Fermat-Euler theorem. The Primitive Root Theorem says that there are $\phi(p - 1)$ primitive roots, and we must find a prime such that the smallest primitive root is greater than $10$. But how do we proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [A046145](http://oeis.org/A046145) in the OEIS.  It looks like the answer is:

> $191$.

Comment: How might we find this analytically, though?

Comment: @Ayesha, some of the references at http://oeis.org/A001918 might help.  My impression is that there is no analytic approach, you just have to look at the primes pretty much one by one.  Was this really a (time-limited) contest problem?

Comment: I'm actually not sure about that, but I do believe it was written for time-limited conditions.